# Make use of PHP sitemap generator script without extension

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I have an asp.net mvc site with clean urls i.e. no extension. For ex http://www.example.com/country/what-is-the-name.

I want to use the following script to spider and generate the sitemap for me. But to my bad luck it only crawls the main domain url and nothing else. I believe this might be cause of extension variable. How can i modify this script in such a way extension is not required or any other way to make it work

PHP Script : http://www.plop.at/en/php.html

Please tell me what to edit in the above script at the given url to make it work my asp.net mvc website. Basic things i know.

Comment: find one that crawls the whole site

Comment: that's what this is i guess